# JBoss ESB service is not working concurrently

Tags: java, jboss, esb

In my project I have 2 services. The first one has defined sql listener with maxThreads=5 in jboss-esb.xml file. The second one is just a simple service with one action. Now what I am doing is receiving from listener rows from database then I am creating message from them and sending this message to the second service. What I noticed is that the first service works kinda concurrently only when I use ServiceInvoker with deliverAsync method. But then when the second service receive message it works sequentially. Should I change something in configuration or what? Why the second service does not work concurrently as well?

EDIT:
Ok I find solution by myself. The second service doesn't have any defined listener because message from the first one to the second one is sent by ServiceInvoker so all I had to do was to add one line in the second service definition:

```
<property name="maxThreads" value="5" />
```